# ASP.Net Remove Sidebar from Wizard Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspwizard

Any ideas how to remove/hide/disable and make invisible the sidebar (with all of the links in it) from a Wizard Control?

Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [Wizard.DisplaySideBar Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard.displaysidebar.aspx) like so:

```
<asp:Wizard ID="wizard1" runat="server" DisplaySideBar="false">...
```

Comment: Thanks, couldn't see that for looking.

Answer (score -1):

You can find it in:

Wizard properties. 
highlight the .aspx form code then look for it in behavior.
[click Image where to find it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gusQV.jpg)